# CacheFlux: How to synchronize lookup/ onCacheMissResume?

Tags: java, caching, spring-webflux, project-reactor

When using Spring Cache in a Spring Boot application, whe can use the `sync`attribute to make sure only one thread/ request updates the cache at a time:

```
@Cacheable(value = "myCacheName", key = "myCacheKey", sync = true)
```

Since `@Cacheable` is not supported yet in Spring WebFlux we can take a programmatic approach using [reactor.cache.CacheFlux](https://projectreactor.io/docs/extra/snapshot/api/reactor/cache/CacheFlux.html) and [reactor.cache.CacheMono](https://projectreactor.io/docs/extra/snapshot/api/reactor/cache/CacheMono.html) to work with [org.springframework.cache.CacheManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html).

But what is the proper way to sync requests so, e.g. there will be only one remote call or db access `onCacheMissResume`?

The following does not work, of course, as the Flux/ Mono hasn't been "executed" yet:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import reactor.cache.CacheFlux;
import reactor.cache.CacheMono;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.core.publisher.Signal;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;


@Component
public class ReactiveCacheManager {

    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;


    public <KEY, VALUE> Mono<VALUE> lookupMono(String cacheName, KEY cacheKey, Class<VALUE> type, Mono<VALUE> defaulValue) {
        synchronized (cacheManager) {
            return CacheMono.lookup(key -> readMonoFromCache(cacheName, key, type), cacheKey)
                    .onCacheMissResume(defaulValue)
                    .andWriteWith((key, valueSignal) -> writeMonoToCache(cacheName, key, valueSignal));
        }
    }


    public <KEY, VALUE> Flux<VALUE> lookupFlux(String cacheName, KEY cacheKey, Flux<VALUE> defaulValue) {
        synchronized (cacheManager) {
            return CacheFlux.<KEY, VALUE>lookup(key -> readFluxFromCache(cacheName, key), cacheKey)
                    .onCacheMissResume(defaulValue)
                    .andWriteWith((key, valueSignal) -> writeFluxToCache(cacheName, key, valueSignal));
        }
    }
    [...]
}
```

Comment: There was [issue](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons/issues/162) about cache stampeding, but it wasn't resolved. You could try Caffeine AsyncCache. Or [this tool](https://github.com/alex-pumpkin/reactor-lock) for `Mono`

Comment: @AlexanderPankin Thanks, I will have a look at it. We're currently using EhCache.

Comment: Do you have any solution? I wrote special executor with internal `FluxProcessor` which provide sync between context (Not thread). So method is still reactive and without blocks.

Comment: @Mister_Jesus our current solution is to wrap the lookups with:  `Mono.fromCallable(() -> { synchronized (cacheKey) {`. Not sure, if this is correct, though.

Comment: As i said, you can use special object which will wraps all passed publishers. I made the class which has inner UnicastProcessor. It always wants 1 element. I pass any publisher with sink via `Mono/Flux#create`. In `hookOnNext` i simply subscribe to it (All signals from subscribed/passed published propagates to already created sink). On terminate of subscribed publisher i request next one. In future may be i will publish to github this class as lib. And this is without any locks.

Comment: @Mister_Jesus please let me know if you publish anything

Comment: @Puce, I have already added the link.